# Python: use regular expression to remove the white space from all lines

Tags: python, regex

`^(\s+)` only removes the whitespace from the first line.  How do I remove the front whitespace from all the lines?

Comment: whitespace includes newline characters, which means that everything will end up on a single line, if you use this on a multiline string. show us some input so we can help understand the question!

Comment: @rdrey: Actually, `^` in multiline mode matches *after* each newline, so that won't be a problem (except for "\n\n"). See my answer.

Comment: thanks for that correction. learning something new every day :D

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Python's regex module does not default to [multi-line `^` matching](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), so you need to specify that flag explicitly.

```
r = re.compile(r"^\s+", re.MULTILINE)
r.sub("", "a\n b\n c") # "a\nb\nc"

# or without compiling (only possible for Python 2.7+ because the flags option
# didn't exist in earlier versions of re.sub)

re.sub(r"^\s+", "", "a\n b\n c", flags = re.MULTILINE)

# but mind that \s includes newlines:
r.sub("", "a\n\n\n\n b\n c") # "a\nb\nc"
```

It's also possible to include the flag inline to the pattern:

```
re.sub(r"(?m)^\s+", "", "a\n b\n c")
```

An easier solution is to avoid regular expressions because the original problem is very simple:

```
content = 'a\n b\n\n c'
stripped_content = ''.join(line.lstrip(' \t') for line in content.splitlines(True))
# stripped_content == 'a\nb\n\nc'
```

Comment: `"^\s+"` also removes empty lines

Answer (score 12):

you can try `strip()` if you want to remove front and back, or `lstrip()` if front

```
>>> s="  string with front spaces and back   "
>>> s.strip()
'string with front spaces and back'
>>> s.lstrip()
'string with front spaces and back   '

for line in open("file"):
    print line.lstrip()
```

If you really want to use regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("^\s+","",s) # remove the front
'string with front spaces and back   '
>>> re.sub("\s+\Z","",s)
'  string with front spaces and back'  #remove the back
```

Answer (score 8):

@AndiDog acknowledges in his (currently accepted) answer that it munches consecutive newlines.

Here's how to fix that deficiency, which is caused by the fact that `\n` is BOTH whitespace and a line separator. What we need to do is make an re class that includes only whitespace characters other than newline.

We want `whitespace and not newline`, which can't be expressed directly in an re class. Let's rewrite that as `not not (whitespace and not newline)` i.e. `not(not whitespace or not not newline` (thanks, [Augustus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) i.e. `not(not whitespace or newline)` i.e. `[^\S\n]` in `re` notation.

So:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?m)^[^\S\n]+", "", "  a\n\n   \n\n b\n c\nd  e")
'a\n\n\n\nb\nc\nd  e'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nowhite = ''.join(mytext.split())
```

NO whitespace will remain like you asked (everything is put as one word). More useful usualy is to join everything with `' '` or `'\n'` to keep words separately.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the re.MULTILINE option:

```
re.sub("(?m)^\s+", "", text)
```

The "(?m)" part enables multiline.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need regular expressions for this most of the time. If you are only looking to remove *common* indentation across multiple lines, try the `textwrap` module:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> messy_text = " grrr\n whitespace\n everywhere"
>>> print textwrap.dedent(messy_text)
grrr
whitespace
everywhere
```

Note that if the indentation is irregular, this will maintained:

```
>>> very_messy_text = " grrr\n \twhitespace\n everywhere"
>>> print textwrap.dedent(very_messy_text)
grrr
        whitespace
everywhere
```